# Moving around inequalities for limits

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

My calculus book states the following:

$$|x^2-9|=|x-3||x+3|<7|x-3|$$
$$|x^2-9|<\epsilon$$

But I am confused about this part:

$|x^2-9|<\epsilon$ for $|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$

How is it okay to say this?

How do they go from

$$|x-3||x+3|<7|x-3|$$
$$|x-3||x+3|<\epsilon$$

to

$|x^2-9|<\epsilon$ for $|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $$|x-3||x+3|<7|x-3|$$ and $$|x-3|<\frac\epsilon 7,$$ combining the two inequalities gives you $$|x-3||x+3|<7|x-3|<7\cdot \frac\epsilon 7 = \epsilon.$$

Comment: How did you get $|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$

Comment: You already have that. The sentence "$|x^2-9|<\epsilon$ for $|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$" means "if the statement $|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$ is true, then the statement $|x^2-9|<\epsilon$ is also true."